# Excel, advanced data consolidation

Tags: vba, excel

I have several very large data sets that I need to consolidate. These data sets come from different studies, so the formatting etc is disparate.

What I would like is a macro that can search for a column value (eg. Name = George) and then  copy and paste each value in the ROW where it occurs into a new column on a different worksheet.

Example:

[image]

Comment: You said you want to *search* specific entry. Your sample shows all the names stacked and not just *George*. And also, maybe you could add what have you tried to accomplish this? That would be great.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

I have little VBA experience, so I haven't tried much. I tried Pivot tables but they didn't work well. I DO want the 'output' names stacked, to make this data fit with another data set where the names are stacked and repeated for each entry.

Comment: So literally you just want the input data returned as stacked? Not just a specific name or record but all?

Comment: Yes, for every colour/year combination in the 'input' example, I want a new line in the output, as such having 3 George, 3 Jim etc. lines in the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the full code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub myMacro()

    ' decleration
    Dim rowMain As Integer, rowNewSheet As Integer
        rowMain = 2
        rowNewSheet = 1

    Dim columnOffset As Integer
        columnOffset = 0

    ' main sheet where data is
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select

    ' loop through all names
    Do While Range("A" & rowMain).Value <> ""

        Do While Range("B" & rowMain - 1).Offset(0, columnOffset).Value <> ""

            ' Name
            Application.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & rowNewSheet).Value = Range("A" & rowMain).Value

            ' Year
            Application.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & rowNewSheet).Value = Range("B1").Offset(0, columnOffset).Value

            ' Color
            Application.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & rowNewSheet).Value = Range("B" & rowMain).Offset(0, columnOffset).Value

            ' next line
            rowNewSheet = rowNewSheet + 1
            columnOffset = columnOffset + 1

        Loop

        ' next Name
        columnOffset = 0
        rowMain = rowMain + 1

    Loop

End Sub
```

This should do the job you're looking for. Let me know if there are problems.

Comment: Thanks again, I'm testing this now and will get back shortly.

Comment: Make sure the sheet name where data is stored is called "Sheet1" and the new sheet where data will go is called "Sheet2". Also, you can change the value here //rowMain = 2// if you data sheet has extra heading. For example, if data start at row 3, change the value to 3.

Comment: THIS WORKS WONDERFULLY! Thanks so much for your assistance. You have no idea how much time you have saved me. +1,000 upvotes to you friend!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the example you provided, ignoring the large headings, the macro will look something like this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub myMacro()

    Dim row As Integer
        row = 1

    Application.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & row).Value = Range("A" & row + 1).Value
    Application.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & row).Value = Range("B" & row).Value
    Application.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & row).Value = Range("B" & row + 1).Value

End Sub
```

The code would change based on how your data is organized. But the above code show the basic idea on how it might be done. One way of many.

Comment: That works really well for a single line! Is there a way to make it repeat for all rows and columns?

Comment: You could add a simple loop for each row and columns. Quite simple and easy if the number of rows and columns are static.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this not very neat solution.
Also, for this to work, you need to change your source data into a table.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheet1
    Dim id, ids, yr, yrs
    Dim rng As Range

    With Application
        Set rng = ws.ListObjects("Table1").HeaderRowRange
        Set rng = rng.Offset(0, 1).Resize(, rng.Columns.Count - 1)
        yrs = .Transpose(rng)
        ids = .Transpose(ws.Range("Table1[Name]"))
    End With

    Dim lrow As Long
    For Each id In ids
        Dim r As Range: Set r = ws.Range("Table1[Name]").Find(id)
        Dim i As Long: i = 1
        For Each yr In yrs
            With ws
                lrow = .Range("A:A").Find("*", [A1], , , , xlPrevious).Row
                .Range("A" & lrow).Offset(1, 0).Value = id
                .Range("A" & lrow).Offset(1, 1).Value = yr
                .Range("A" & lrow).Offset(1, 2).Value = r.Offset(0, i).Value
            End With
            i = i + 1
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

**Result:**

[image]

I did change the source data into a *Table* so I can take advantage of the *ListObject*.
In the example, table name is **Table1**. You can change to suit in case you want to take this route.
Anyways, HTH even though most of it will be blurry since you pointed out you have minimal experience in coding.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another method using a Class to create a User Defined Type so as to collect each Name/Year/Color combo, then output the results.  It can be used with any number of "Years", Names or colors.

This first code goes into a class module that you should rename **NameData**  (see Chip Pearsons web page on Classes)

=============================

```
Option Explicit
Private pName As String
Private PYear As Long
Private pColor As String

Public Property Get Name() As String
    Name = pName
End Property
Public Property Let Name(Value As String)
    pName = Value
End Property

Public Property Get Color() As String
    Color = pColor
End Property
Public Property Let Color(Value As String)
    pColor = Value
End Property

Public Property Get Year() As Long
    Year = PYear
End Property
Public Property Let Year(Value As Long)
    PYear = Value
End Property
```

==================================

This second code goes into a Regular Module:

================================

```
Option Explicit
Sub ReArrange()
    Dim cND As NameData
    Dim colND As Collection
    Dim vSrc As Variant
    Dim vRes() As Variant
    Dim rRes As Range
    Dim I As Long, J As Long

'Results will go here
Set rRes = Range("a20") 'could be on another worksheet

'Read source data into array
'Many ways to select the data, depending on your "real" setup
vSrc = Range("a2").CurrentRegion

'Collect each Name/Year/Color combo
Set colND = New Collection
For I = 2 To UBound(vSrc, 1)
    For J = 2 To UBound(vSrc, 2)
    Set cND = New NameData
    With cND
        .Name = vSrc(I, 1) 'Name always in first column
        .Year = vSrc(1, J) 'Year always in first row
        .Color = vSrc(I, J) 'Color at intersection

        'add to collection
        colND.Add cND
    End With
    Next J
Next I

'Dimension and populate output array
ReDim vRes(0 To colND.Count, 1 To UBound(vSrc, 2) - 1)

'Column Labels
vRes(0, 1) = "Name"
vRes(0, 2) = "Year"
vRes(0, 3) = "Color"

J = 0
For I = 1 To colND.Count
    J = J + 1
    With colND(I)
        vRes(J, 1) = .Name
        vRes(J, 2) = .Year
        vRes(J, 3) = .Color
    End With
Next I

With rRes.Resize(UBound(vRes, 1) + 1, UBound(vRes, 2))
    .Resize(Cells.Rows.Count - .Row).Clear
    .Value = vRes
End With
```

## End Sub

You can easily modify this to put the results on a different worksheet, if you like, and it will accomodate as many columns/rows of data as you might have.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I was able to get this done with the method above though.